# module magento 1.8 reports

Tags: php, magento-1.8

i have few issues, which ive been trying to see what can be done but have no luck,

i am trying to accomplish the following

when admin goes to get product totals they want to be able to get the values per there "pickup date" instead of "order date"

how can i edit or where can i edit the file so i can do that??

when a customer orders they choose a pickup date so i need to be able to use that custom section to get the values of total product orders.

---

also i am using fooman print order module i have 3 custom order options i need added where and how do i do that i have found no support for this thanks

Comment: pretty much i am looking to figure out the following : get product totals by custom order attribute magento

Comment: any ideas to the question?